# select case with order by in jpa

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

```
SELECT * FROM orderTable order by 
CASE priority when 'CRITICAL' THEN 1 
   when 'HIGH' then 2 
   when 'MEDIUM' then 3 
   when 'LOW' then 4 
   when 'NOT_ASSIGNED' then 5 
end ASC ,
CreatedAt ASC;
```

This is my mysql query and its working. Database column `priority` is string type and that string having following priority

I wanted it in jpa language like

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();       
CriteriaQuery<T> cq = cb.createQuery(entityClass);
Root<T> root = cq.from(entityClass);
cb.selectCase().when(cb.equal(root.get("priority"), "CRITICAL"), 1)
    .when(cb.equal(root.get("priority"), "HIGH"), 2)
    .when(cb.equal(root.get("priority"), "MEDIUM"), 3)
    .when(cb.equal(root.get("priority"), "LOW"), 4)
    .when(cb.equal(root.get("priority"), "NOT_ASSIGNED"), 5).;
Order temp2 = cb.desc(root.get("priority"));
cq = cq.orderBy(temp2);
```

this is not working it return result only sort by string priority. The select case is not applied on criteria build query.

Answer (score 14):

You select with the line `cb.desc(root.get("priority"));` the original "piority". Care, at your first example you use asc and second desc. I have also added a default case.

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<TableTest> cq = cb.createQuery(TableTest.class);
    Root<TableTest> root = cq.from(TableTest.class);
    Expression<Object> caseExpression = cb.selectCase()
            .when(cb.equal(root.get("priority"), cb.literal("CRITICAL")), 1)
            .when(cb.equal(root.get("priority"), cb.literal("HIGH")), 2)
            .when(cb.equal(root.get("priority"), cb.literal("MEDIUM")), 3)
            .when(cb.equal(root.get("priority"), cb.literal("LOW")), 4)
            .when(cb.equal(root.get("priority"), cb.literal("NOT_ASSIGNED")), 5)
            .otherwise(6);
    Order temp2 = cb.desc(caseExpression);
    cq = cq.orderBy(temp2);
```

Comment: can I able to loop this when statement?

Answer (score 0):

We can also use *javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder.SimpleCase*

```
// ArrayList<T> order - Define Custom order ArrayList // {"HIGH", "MEDIUM", "LOW", "NOT_ASSIGNED"}
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<TableTest> query = cb.createQuery(TableTest.class);
Root<TableTest> root = query.from(TableTest.class);
query.select(root);
Path<String> priority = root.get("priority");
SimpleCase<String, Integer> orderCase = builder.selectCase(priority);
int i;
for (i = 0; i < order.size(); i++) {
    orderCase = orderCase.when(order.get(i),i); // .when("HIGH", 0);
}
query.orderBy(cb.asc(orderCase.otherwise(i)));
entityManager.createQuery(query);
```

Rather than using *cb.selectCase().when(#)*, we can use *CriteriaBuilder.SimpleCase*. because of we can easily loop it.

- If we have a huge number of orders.
- Order requests based on user preferences.